# I would like to prompt Mac OS X 10.6.8 to download Rosetta by running a dedicated PPC application

Tags: applications, install, snow-leopard, powerpc, rosetta

Does anyone know where I can download a **dedicated PPC** application to try?

I would like to find one to attempt to run in my install of OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard so it will either prompt me to install Rosetta, or open and thus confirm that Rosetta's already installed and fully functional, which I believe it is not.  For example, within System Profiler under Software -> Applications, "Rosetta" is nowhere to be found.

The ultimate goal here for me is to get Rosetta fully installed. (And no, unfortunately I don't have the original install DVD.)  So any comments helping me in that direction would be greatly appreciated!

### Thanks!

Comment: for Rosetta 2, a command (`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`) works - maybe Snow Leopard has the same?

Comment: Most apps of that vintage will be universal Binaries for both PPC and Intel -- you can make them launch in PPC mode in Get Info.

Comment: That is pretty much what I posted as a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/690574) to the IconDaemon's answer. I did not mention having to first go to Get Info.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, because I don't have A Snow Leopard system running, but [this site](https://ppcappstore.wordpress.com) looks promising.

> The PPCAppStore is a software distribution platform, for PowerPC macs, compatible with MacOS 10.4 Tiger, MacOS 10.5 Leopard and MacOS 10.6 SnowLeopard OS.
> The PPCAppStore is a project developed by Adrian Oprea, a computer enthusiast and is freely distributed on a non-profit basis.
> It allows users to download essential applications to keep their PowerPC macs alive.
> The purpose of the store is to keep a copy of the applications, because lately the platform PowerPC is no longer supported and developers not provide anymore the version for PowerPC macs.

Comment: This "PPCAppStore" is good and all, the problem is that I think 100% of those applications it offers are compatible with Intel-based Macs running Snow Leopard.  I tried downloading some from that "Store" and they all worked on my machine.  One (coconutBattery) even said "Intel" in its window, indicating its compatibility with Intel.  I need applications that are 100% PPC and PPC only. (-Maybe iLife '03? -Something *way* back...) Thanks though!

Comment: I tried coconutBattery using OS X Snow Leopard version 10.6. First, I needed to select "Open using Rosetta", as shown in [this image](https://imgur.com/58MWX1f). Afterwards, opening coconutBattery caused the popup asking to install Rosetta.